# How can I replace/update specific HTML tag inside string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, html-parsing, spfx

I have a SPFx modern webpart, using React and TypeScript. I am consuming the Microsoft Graph API to fetch messages from a Teams Channel:

```
  this.context.msGraphClientFactory
    .getClient()
    .then((client: MSGraphClient): void =>{
      client
        .api(`/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages/delta`)
        .filter(maxPastDateFilter)
        .version("beta")
        .get((error, response: any, rawResponse?: any) => { ... }
```

I receive the messages and can display them, but I noticed that some messages have images in them, which are also hosted inside the Team Chats, this is known as "hostedContent". Inside the messages I receive (JSON) there is a property `body`, which has a child `content` that contains the message body and also the links to those `hostedContent` images. This looks like this:

```
content:'<div><div><img alt="Sticker image, I CAN FIX IT" src="https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/59b9b7d4-fd66-43cb-ae2b-03b4705f819f/channels/19:c73e19f4bb1841c9830f233d0d745eab@thread.skype/messages/1584028726132/hostedContents/aWQ9eF8wLXdldS1kMi05YjNhYWUxNGViY2Y2Njg5NzcyMTdmNGY2OTQxNzA0Zix0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vZXUtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLXdldS1kMi05YjNhYWUxNGViY2Y2Njg5NzcyMTdmNGY2OTQxNzA0Zi92aWV3cy9pbWdv/$value" style="width:376px; height:251px"></div>\n</div>'
```

When I display this content as HTML inside my WebPart, the content gets rendered but the images do not, they return a 401 unauthorized response. I believe the needed authorization token is not sent. I'm not exactly sure why this happens, as the current user is logged in and should have the right to access the resource but I guess, that it doesn't work this way as the `src` attribute does not send the required authentication bearer token with the request.

So, to get the images, I found out that there is an API call to get the images:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
Well, it's basically the URL value from the `src` attribute that I need to call and then I could convert the received image into a BLOB and use it.

My idea was to make the API call using the `graphClient` (as seen in the example above), convert the response image to a BLOB and then display it by replacing the existing `src` attribute of the `img` tag with the BLOB-url.

Well, that's pretty much context :-) - so the question is, how can I now best parse this string (representing HTML) and replace said `img` `src` attribute?

Comment: Convert the content into actual HTML elements (`.createElement("div")`, `.innerHTML = ...`). Then just get the `<img>` tags with `.querySelectorAll()`.

Comment: OK, sounds good, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the tip of Andreas I was able to implement a solution.

Here is an example (not using the image tag, as it has a more complex logic in it to replace the source):

1st create a temporal div to work with out tags:

```
    let temporalDivElement = document.createElement("div");
    temporalDivElement.innerHTML = message.content;
```

Then, in this example, I search for a tag called "attachments", I find all, iterate over them and replace them with a `SPAN` tag.

```
// Attachments
const attachmentTags: NodeListOf<HTMLImageElement> = temporalDivElement.querySelectorAll(`attachment`);
attachmentTags.forEach((attachmentTag) => {
  let attachmentRemovedLink = document.createElement("a");
  attachmentRemovedLink.innerText = "Attachment Replaced";
  attachmentRemovedLink.href = urlXy;
  attachmentTag.parentNode.replaceChild(attachmentRemovedLink, attachmentTag);
});
```

What's cool, and I didn't now initially, with `querySelectorAll` you can not only select stuff by a tag name, but you can also implement more complex scenarios.

For example with this selector I can select all image tags that contain a specific `src` attribute value:

```
const imgTags: NodeListOf<HTMLImageElement> = temporalDivElement.querySelectorAll(`img[src*="/messages/${message.id}/hostedContents/"]`);
```